# Numeric password entry to force numeric keypad

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

With normal numeric input fields, Bootstrap allows you to put a class on the control to force the numeric entry keypad on mobile devices.

Is there a way to do this with a password type entry, that is a 4 digit numeric PIN?

I have tried this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Pin, new { @class = "form-control input-money", @type = "password", @min = 0, @step = "any" })
```

But it still shows the alphabet keyboard.

The Pin is declared, in the model, as:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "A verification PIN is required")]
[MinLength(4, ErrorMessage = "A valid PIN is required")]
[MaxLength(4, ErrorMessage = "A valid PIN is required")]
public string Pin { get; set; }
```

I think the "type=password" overrides the "input-money" (Which, is what I think causes numeric input).

Is this possible?
I want the numeric keyboard to show on mobile devices.

Comment: Couldn't that be considered an additional security feature; this way an attacker has less insight into what the password-characters should be.

Comment: This is just a verification of the user within the application. He's already logged in - and is updating something we just need quick verification on. Normal login is still the main entry method.